# Windows loses screen layout

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, display, layout

I'm using a HP Compaq 6510b laptop running Windows Vista 64-bit with an additional 24" screen.

Windows is constantly forgetting the screen layout, even though I didn't disconnect anything. A simple reboot or waking up from standby is enough so that the screens are rearranged.

Do you have any solution to this?

My inconvenient solution for now is to disable the build-in screen and work just on the external screen. But I'd like to use both.

Comment: I have the same problem on a Dell desktop computer. I have ended up disabling power saving stuff that turn off the screens or put the machine in sleep mode. Use a blank screen or neutral screen saver instead. Would like to have the screens off, of course, but was too annoying to have to rearrange them every time I came back from lunch etc... So I do hope someone have a good solution to this problem! (Is Windows 7 any better at this?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have an HP 8440w atm, which I use with several monitor-setups, depending on where I use it.

I use the built in device profile manager which comes with the ATI-video card. I beleive this is also accomplishable with nVidias device drivers.

There's always some manual step I have to take to quick-switch resolutions on all monitors, but this is easily accomplished by having user-profiles that remember monitor position / resolution / type. Meaning I have 4 user profiles that are either 3 clicks away, or changeable via shortcuts (ex: ctrl + alt + shift + key):

- Work: dual screen with docking
- Work: 20" + laptop (left side of screen) on stand (not very ergonomic, but there's not enough docking stations to go around!)
- Home: laptop (right side of screen) + 24" screen
- Everywhere: laptop only

I'd recommend checking out the default drivers suppled for your graphics card.

Comment: I have the Intel GMA 965 drivers and indeed you can create profiles.
Thanks for the hint, I'll be using this now even though I consider this to be a Windows problem...

Comment: True, that would of course be natural, but seeing as to how many ways people love to customize their desktops, I can understand that they haven't jumped too far into this issue.